# Specific rule for if a field doesn't validate (form_validation in CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form that allows a user to add a new user, it contains validation that checks to see if the user already exists in the database:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('newuser_email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]');
```

However in cases where a user DOES already exist, rather than just sending back a static string, I'd like to be able to run my own function (as in this case the user still needs to be added to a new table, but not added to the database as a new user).

I've had a good search but can't see anything relating to this - only callbacks, which are different. I essentially need to say:

If `newuser_email` is `not_unique[user.email]`, then do `this`

I never need to return an error to the user for this case, only for 'valid_email'.

Thanks

Comment: You can either run your own check without the validation if ( not_unique(xxx) ) or use the ugly-way by matching the result of the built-in function "form_error('field name')"

Comment: I'm @ahmad. I'm not sure I follow. The form_error() function is for reporting errors in the view, I need to run a function based on the error result in the controller. if(not_unique[xxx]) is exactly what I want to do, conceptually, but how? What code achieves this logic? That's essentially my question…

Comment: remove the check from validation & validate it manually when all other validation passes, use email helper to validate the email, then check in the database if it's there do some stuffs you want if not create the user.

Comment: So just do it all manually then? I was kind of hoping there was a cleaner way of working within the validation tools.